# Why can't I create cookies in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

For some reason, I can't seem to create cookies using Symfony 2. This is my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    var_dump($this->getRequest()->cookies->all());

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', 'bar'));

    var_dump($response->headers->getCookies());

    return $response;
}
```

When I run this controller, I see what I expect: An array containing the "PHPSESSID" cookie and an array containing the new cookie that I'm trying to create. When I reload the page, I expect to see the new cookie in the first array, but I don't. Nothing changes on reload.

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong? I've been staring at these lines for like 15 minutes now.

---

- [Docs: Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)
- [Docs: Response](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html)
- [Docs: Cookie](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.html)
- [How to set a cookie using Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#setting-cookies)

Comment: Silly question, but maybe : are you sure cookies are enabled on your browser?

Comment: Remove the first var_dump, it's sending content.

Comment: @MisterJ: Obviously, as I'm using PHP sessions.

Comment: @vascowhite: It's not often I get the perfect answer as a comment :P I urge you to submit your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first `var_dump()` is sending content, so further headers cannot be sent. Remove it and your code will work.